# C++ set objects within an array to NULL

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, pointers

I have a `class Modal`

```
class Modal {
private:
   A* obj1;
   B* obj2;
}
```

where A is B's parent class

```
class A {
};

class B : public A {
};
```

in the destructor of `Modal` I want to set `obj1` and `obj2` to `NULL`

I created a convenience method:

```
void remove(A*& obj) {
    if (obj == NULL) { return; }
    obj = NULL;
}
```

and in the destructor I do something like this:

```
A* objects[] = { obj1, obj2 };
for(auto obj: objects) { remove(obj); }
```

But it does not set the `obj1` and `obj2` values to `NULL`
If I call directly:

```
remove(obj1);
```

it works as it should.
So what am I doing wrong with the array?

Also:
The reason why I put `obj1` and `obj2` into an array is because I will have more objects and I want to keep the code for the removal short.

Comment: Are you sure `obj1` isn't `NULL`? Use a debugger here, would help.

Comment: There are a number of issues here, but first off, there is no point to resetting a class's direct members inside its destructor. They're about to be unusable anyway.

Comment: There is no need to set `obj1` and `obj2` to `NULL` in the destructor of `Modal`.  As soon as the destructor completes, the pointers won't exist any more anyway.    If you're trying to set them to NULL to force the objects the point to to be cleaned up, then that won't work either - unlike other languages, C++ does not work that way at all.

Comment: Change the loop to `for (auto &obj : objects) {remove (obj);}`.  Note the ampersand.   This will set `obj1` and `obj2` to `NULL`.   AS per my previous comment this doesn't achieve much anyway, since the pointers `obj1` and `obj2` will not exist when the destructor completes.

Comment: The `&` did not change anything :/ The object somehow still is not `NULL`

Comment: @Peter that ampersand only helps clear the pointers in the `objects` array. It will not help clear the pointers from which the array was initialized.

Comment: @JaMiT - yep.    The OP still hasn't explained the need to set `obj1` and `obj2` to `NULL` in a destructor anyway, given that they will cease to exist (i.e. they can't be used at all) after the destructor returns - since the object that contains them doesn't exist any more.    Setting something to `NULL`, and then having it immediately cease to even exist, seems rather pointless.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not set `obj1` and `obj2` to NULL because at no point do you try to do so. What your code does is set the elements of the `objects` array to NULL. Those elements are initialized to the *values* of `obj1` and `obj2`; they are not references to `obj1` and `obj2`.

Not to mention that this looks like unnecessary busy work for the program. Think about why you are doing these things. Why must the pointers be set to NULL? Why check to see if a pointer is NULL before setting it to NULL? Why are you setting pointers to NULL without first deleting the memory they point to? (Why are you not using smart pointers?) Why not have the array of pointers be part of the class definition (replacing the individual pointer definitions)?

---

*Edit:* I mentioned smart pointers, but perhaps I should not assume that everyone knows what they are? I will attempt to give a definition (what they are) without going into a tutorial (how to use them). Apologies in advance if my statements are not as precise as they should be.
A **smart pointer** is a pointer that knows how to clean up after itself. For me, I expect a smart pointer to satisfy two criteria:

1. Its use is similar to that of a pointer.
2. Adding it to a scenario does not require adding any cleanup code. *(The cleanup code is very short!)*

So, loosely speaking, a smart pointer is a pointer with a destructor. The essence of the concept is the following:

```
class PA {
    A * ptr;
    ~PA { delete ptr; }
}
```

Of course, an actual implementation would need to flesh this out a lot (see, for example, [std::unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)). Still, any modifications to this core are really "just" specializing the concept to a particular purpose.

Comment: this.. expresses state of my panic when I try read code like that.

Answer (score 0):

I copy your code to https://wandbox.org/, then in loop output the address of obj, but not have error.
the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class A {
};

class B : public A {
};

class Modal {
private:
   A* obj1;
   B* obj2;
};

void remove(A*& obj) {
    if (obj == NULL) { return; }
    obj = NULL;
}

int main()
{
    A* objects[] = { new A, new A };
    for(auto obj: objects) 
    { 
        std::cout << obj << " ";
        remove(obj); 
        std::cout << obj << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the output:

0xfea160 0

0xfea180 0

Comment: Yeah, there is no error, but the values are not `NULL` and that's the problem :/

Comment: Change the loop in `main()` to `for (auto &obj : objects)`.   That will set the pointers to `NULL`.    Note the ampersand.  It will also result in a memory leak, since the `new` expressions are not matched with a corresponding `delete`.

Comment: Yeah, Peter is right, here show have a &, I am worry, that jast value copy